# Website can scroll, but Jquery scroll calculate stops at certain points

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset, scrolltop

I'm using the following code to calculate how many pixels the user has scrolled offset from top:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollTop);
});
```

However, at some points on the site, it just 'pauses'. It says you don't scroll, although I am scrolling. I've tried numerous scripts, but the console keeps telling me the same thing.

[This is the site](http://checkspot.nl/appendo/website/)

At this point that's all information I can give, since that's all I found. Hopefully someone can help me! Thanks!

**Update**
- It only pauses around somewhere near 280px for me.

Comment: It doesn't pause for me. I get all down to 5601px

Comment: It works fine over the whole page, except for around 280px, halfway when the first 'slide' is nearing the top.

Comment: It works for me (google chrome)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I didn't want to close it, just to point out for duplicate, my bad!

Comment: @A.Wolff Although it isn't a duplicate. The previous question was about having a working code. This is a page-wide problem, nothing related to the jQuery code itself.

Comment: Ya fixed it, again my bad!

Comment: Np. Thanks for fixing! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing "overflow-x: hidden" from the body element seems to solve this issue.